# Oil-fired furnace sight window repair

Tags: repair, furnace

I have an 20+ year old oil burner and a tankless boiler/furnace. There is a small round (2-3" diameter) window above the burner that lets you see the flame, I assume as an aid to tuning the burner.

After noticing a slightly smoky smell in the basement I found that this window was leaning outward from the wall of the furnace. There is an e-clip there as well. My assumption is that the metal groove for the e-clip has degraded enough that it can't hold the window in place any longer.

Is there an easy and safe way to repair this myself? I was thinking of some sort of high-temperature adhesive but I'm not sure what to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using epoxy to hold the glass itself in place would be a bad choice, as the thermal expansion of the glass is different than the surrounding materials - this is why a clip is used rather than a more secure solution.  The clip allows movement.

If you can figure out how it was originally attached, and repair that (perhaps with the aid of a welding and/or machine shop then that would be the ideal solution.

However, using epoxy to hold wire or a metal clip of your own design in place that holds the glass in place would also work out well enough.

**Note: If the item that was holding the glass in place was rusted/damaged enough that it no longer serves its function, chances are *very* good that the heat exchanger is also nearing the end of its life, or already has pin holes, which would allow combustion gasses to enter the building.  Do a thorough inspection.**

Answer (score 0):

There certainly are high-temperature epoxies that should do the trick for this (J-B Weld comes to mind,  it's rated for a constant 500 deg. F but you should confirm that's higher than this part of your furnace gets).

But you say "my assumption is that the metal groove for the e-clip has degraded" -- does that mean you're not sure?  I ask because to me this seems like an odd thing to wear out given that it's just holding a stationary piece of glass in place.  Is it possible the clip popped out a long time ago and the groove is just full of soot or rust?

Comment: My assumption is just based on thinking that a properly installed e-ring couldn't pop out on its own. But you are right, it could be something else. I'll be investigating more thoroughly once my holiday company leaves and I can shut off the furnace for a bit. J-B Weld is a possibility; I'm not sure what the temp gets to in that area though.